# conexión remota de Mysql es muy lenta desde C#

Tags: c#, mysql

Estoy creando un aplicación en c# la cual se conecta a una base de datos alojada en un hosting.

la conexión la estoy asiendo a través del archivo app.confing

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="CapaDatos.Properties.Settings.cn" 
         connectionString="user id=DB;password=pass;server=BaseDatos.com;database=BaseDatos"
      providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Todo esto funciona bien al Insertar, actualizar, eliminar y consultas todo esta perfecto,

el detalle que tengo es que demora un poco al hacer algo, por ejemplo si deseo hacer una consulta esto me demora bastante dependiendo de la cantidad de datos que tenga mi tabla, se demora entre 16 y 30 segundo.

Igual si quiero insertar o actualizar un registro demora entre 16 segundos.

Hay alguna manera en acelerar la conexión o tal ves utilizar otro método de conexión.

si me pudieran ayudar se los agradesco

Comment: lo que planteas es lo mas razonable del mundo porque depende de la conexion que tengas de internet, si realizas una consulta que espera obtener cientos de registros esto tiene un peso que hay que transmitir por la red y eso demora su tiempo. es por eso que deberias recuperar la menor cantidad de datos, aplicando paginacion y filtros.
Ademas si te conectas al hosting imagino lo haces por un medio seguro, no? usa una VPN, exponer una base de datos a la red es una locura, con el tiempo te la vulneran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No te conectes nunca directo a una base de datos que expones en el hosting, no al menos sin contar con un enlace seguro por medio de una VPN.

El camino que deberias tomar es exponer un `Web Service` o `WebApi` en el hosting y que la aplicacion consuma los datos por medio de estos con llamas a los servicio

Pero la conexion a la db es local en el servicio quien luego enviara los datos al cliente

[Introducción a ASP.NET Web API 2 (C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)

crea una webapi con asp.net mvc y la publicas en el hosting para que la app consuma los datos desde esta, lo correcto seria que tambien apliques algun medio de autenticacion para acceder a los servicios

Comment: muchas gracias por la orientación voy a modificar mi aplicación